# Convert htaccess rule to nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, mod-rewrite, nginx-config

I have the following rule in apache .htaccess:

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/webroot/files/verification/$1 -f

RewriteRule (.*) files/verification/$1 [L]

All files in directory files/verification/{request_file} accessible by the following link site.com/request_file

How can I configure it on nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /files/verification/$1 break;
}
```

**try_files** Checks the existence of files, if none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made, in this case to 404 page.

**rewrite** is for internally routing the request.

You could find more information in:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite